# Pandas dataframe: Sum of column values where values are list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a sample of dataset. 
[image]

Here each value of the columns is an integer list. The highlighted row is the sum of corresponding column's list. Meaning, the highlighted row of column 'day1' is the sum of all lists in 'Day1' column and so on for the other columns. 
I have tried with sum() with axis but seems like it isnt working for list.
after getting the sum lists, it has to be assigned in a new dataframe with same number of column.Example in picture below,
 
[image]
Any hints of algorithm, links, help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a few rows of your data? also does your actualy values have `...` in it ?

Comment: oh no no. it doesnt have ... in it. The actual list is length of 50 so I just put ... in it.
well its a list and all lists are same size in all column. 
It can be said,
day1             day2           day3   .....     day90
[1,1,1,0]       [1,1,1,0]      [1,1,1,0]       [1,1,1,0]   
[3,2,1,1]       [3,2,1,1]      [3,2,1,1]       [3,2,1,1]   
 [2,1,1,1]       [2,1,1,1]     [2,1,1,1]        [2,1,1,1]
.                    .                  .                     .
.                    .                  .                     .

like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your DataFrame to a NumPy array, like this:
`df.to_numpy()`

And after receive something like:

```py
a = np.random.randint(5, size=(4, 2, 5))
```

Each block here it is your column:

```
array([[[2, 4, 1, 1, 1],
        [4, 0, 1, 4, 0]],

       [[1, 2, 4, 4, 3],
        [0, 1, 4, 4, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
        [3, 0, 4, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 0, 3, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 3, 3, 1]]])
```

Then sum it with axis:

```py
np.sum(a, axis=1)
```

yields:

```
array([[6, 4, 2, 5, 1],
       [1, 3, 8, 8, 3],
       [3, 0, 4, 2, 4],
       [3, 1, 6, 4, 1]])
```

Prepare to create DataFrame

```py
dd = {f'Day{n}':np.array2string(i, separator=',')
      for n,i in enumerate(list(np.sum(ar, axis=1)), start=1)}
```

Create `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dd.values()), index=dd.keys()).T
```

yields:

```
          Day1         Day2         Day3         Day4
0  [6,4,2,5,1]  [1,3,8,8,3]  [3,0,4,2,4]  [3,1,6,4,1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have used another approach and solved it but this solution gave me idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can get all the sum values by values.tolist() and converting them in to int values as follows. Tried a sample and it shows the result as in the image.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
dl = df.values.tolist()

i = 0
for column in df:
    ilist = [sum([int(s) for s in l[i].split(',')]) for l in dl] 
    i = i+1
    print(column, " - ", sum(ilist))
```

- Sample code tried
[image]